# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, file-permissions

I get this error when compile in VS C++ 2010.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cvblobslib.lib'
```

This project is stored on my company server. And I don't have full control.

Is that the problem?

Comment: Is path to server's library location added in "Additional Library Directories" of your project?

Comment: No. That path is input directly in #include command.

Comment: you mean like #include "cvblobslib.lib"?

Comment: "[server-path]\cvblobslib.lib"

Comment: Normal(Project settings) way to link with a library in a Visual Studio solutions is by adding the library name(cvblobslib.lib) in "Linker->Additional Dependencies" and path in "Linker->Additional Library Directories". Can you try this way?

Comment: I just tried that way. But it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably. The linker cannot access the remote lib file. Is there any way you can copy it locally?
If you cannot access the file through the OS, then the linker won't be able to either.

Comment: I can't save that file on my computer. That's prohibited. Is there another ways?

Comment: Can you access that lib file at all? Can you access the source that would allow you to compile the lib file on your computer?

Comment: I can only change the source code. That lib file, I can access with read-only permission.

Comment: If you have read permission, you shouldn't be getting that error. Also, you could copy it.

Comment: I still don't know why that error happen. 
And about copy, first, copy any file from server to personal computer in my company is prohibited; second, I work in a team, and I can't solve problem like that.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the problem in this way:
・ Remove the cpp file which contain #include "[server-path]\cvBlobslib.lib"
・ Add it again to the project.